# How to move breadcrumb bar to the left

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I removed the logo from the sharepoint using below CSS.

```
<style>
.ms-siteicon-img {Display:none; }
.ms-siteicon-img {margin-left: 0px }
</style>
```

how do i remove the white space and move the menu to the left
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add line 2 and 3 to your code:

```
<style>
.ms-breadcrumb-top {position: relative;
    left: -100px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Steff you are a star, I was looking at siteIcon,ms-tableCell, ms-verticalAlignTop with your Firebug tool ;)

Comment: Thank you Rinu :) I'm glad to be able to help you. Thanks for the reward